# print terraform output from list of list to a list of strings

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code, hcl, hashicorp

I am working with vm deployments over AWS with terraform(v1.0.9) as infrastructure as code. i have Terraform output.tf to print two lan a ips and code prints, list of lists like [["ip_a",],["ip_b",]] but i want a list like this ["ip_a", "ip_b"].

output.tf code

```
`output "foo" {
 value = {
 name = "xyz"
 all_ips = tolist(aws_network_interface.vm_a_eni_lan_a.*.private_ips)
}
}`
```

---

printing -->
`"name" = "xyz" "lan_a_ips" = tolist(\[ toset(\[ "10.0.27.116",\]), toset(\[ "10.0.28.201",\]), \])`

but i want "lan_a_ips" = ["10.0.27.116", "10.0.28.201"]

I beleive tweaking output.tf can help. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add `aws_network_interface` to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you have just set the splat expression [1] in a wrong place, i.e., instead of setting `aws_network_interface.vm_a_eni_lan_a.private_ips[*]` you set it to `aws_network_interface.vm_a_eni_lan_a.*.private_ips`. So you only need to change the output value:

```
output "foo" {
 value = {
  name = "xyz"
  all_ips = aws_network_interface.vm_a_eni_lan_a.private_ips[*]
 }
}
```

EDIT: The above applies when only a single instance of an `aws_network_interface` resource is created. For situations where there are multiple instance of this resource created with `count` meta-argument, the following can be used to get a list of IPs:

```
output "foo" {
  value = {
    name    = "xyz"
    all_ips = flatten([for i in aws_network_interface.test[*] : i.private_ips[*]])
  }
}
```

Here, the `for` [2] loop is used to iterate over all the instances of a resource, hence the splat expression when referencing them `aws_network_interface.test[*]`. Additionally, since this will create a list of lists (as `private_ips[*]` returns a list), `flatten` [3] built-in function can be used to create a single list of IP addresses.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for

[3] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten

Comment: Thanks Marko for replying. But we are having two interface lan_a[0] and lan_a[1]. We are using count.index to create two ips.  By tring as u mentioned gives this error -->"aws_network_interface.vm_a_eni_lan_a has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│ 
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     aws_network_interface_vm_a_eni_lan_a[count.index] "

Comment: So there is one private IP but two interfaces?

Comment: no, we have two Interface named lan_a[0] and lan_a[1] and correspondingly two private IP add (like each interface has unique IP)

Comment: I edited the question, it should work with multiple IPs assigned to multiple interfaces as well.